# How to install Mac OS on VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox

I maintain an application I wrote in pure C. Its multiplatform (windows/linux) application. But, unfortunately, my boss wants me to write a version for Mac OS. Since I don't have such computer, its quite a problematic task .. My boss doesnt want to buy even cheapest Mac, he told me to solve it "by myself" (dont know what he ment exactly) :/

I dont need Mac OS (maaaaybe someday, but now I have other, more important expenses), so I thought  to install Mac OS on VirtualBox, just for the time I port my application.

Since all over the internet are just some out dated tutorials, maybe you know the solution, any tutorial, advices, how to install Mac OS on VirtualBox?

P.S. Is such thing even legal ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not OK according to Apple's license: you can only run OS X on Apple hardware. You can use OS X in Virtual box only if the virtual box host is an Apple device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer .. argh, so no solution now :(