# Create Mac OSX on VirtualBox running on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, iso-image

Physical Hardware: Mac Mini running OS X Yosemite 10.10.4

Virtual Box: 5.0.0 r101573

Note: before continuing, yes I saw all the similar questions, such as question #[742854](https://superuser.com/questions/742854/how-to-install-mac-os-on-virtualbox), however the questions do not address my specific problem.

I created a Macintosh OS on Virtual Box. I downloaded, Mac OS X 10.11 from my Apple Developer account. I then converted using DiskUtility the dmg to an iso, cdr which I renamed ISO. I then went to the Storage tab on the Mac OS settings. I specified the Mac ISO as an optical drive. Yes, I specified PIX3 for the chipset and made sure that Optical is the first item in System for the boot order.

Upon launching the OS, I keep getting to the EIFI shell prompt and cannot budge from that. I did check the boot order in the EIFI GUI and it shows optical as the first boot option.

I did watch some of the YouTube videos around and most of the recipes is for Hackintosh, running Mac on Windows, but I am using a real Mac, so Windows and Linux do not enter into the equation at all. I have a legitimate license for the OS too, as I do have a Mac Developer account. I tried the same technique downloading Yosemite, so not the next beta, but ran into the same problem.

What am I missing?